# Android: Changing LinearLayout in a widget

Tags: java, android

I have this really annoying problem:

In my widget, i would like to change the background by code. I noticed on the Google doc than I can easily change the background of an Imageview:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.my_iv, R.drawable.my_bg);
```

Ok, too easy, i want to change now the Linear layout.. What I read about the remoteview id that I can change a Bitmap, Int, Bool, String, etc... but not a drawable. So i guess i cannot use:

```
remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.my_ll,"setBackgroundDrawable",BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawablemy_bg));
```

I am totally disapointed and tried a last idea:

```
views.setInt(R.id.my_ll,"setBackgroundResource",R.drawable.my_bg);
```

But The logcat told me:

> android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException:view:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout can't use
>   method with RemoteViews:
>   setBackgroundResource(int)

I am totally lost and I really don't know what to do...

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the background that way, due to limitations in the `RemoteViews` API.

What you can do is choose a different layout -- one with the background you want -- when you create your `RemoteViews` instance for this particular update.

Comment: yeah, I hadn't thought to this, that would have been a perfect solution.

Unfortunately, i read you too late and meanwhile, I made something with a Framelayout and an imageview.

I don't know if there are many differences or a really better way to do this to improve the perfs of the widget, but both seem to work.

Thank for the answer.

Comment: Hi Profete, could you describe your solution with FrameLayout and ImageView ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/label_bg" android:src="@drawable/widget_label_white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/label"
        android:text="Processes" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#ff000000" android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1" android:shadowRadius="1" />


</FrameLayout>
```

This will make the background image fit the textview nicely.