# Android-widget :  Change app widget background on the fly

Tags: android, android-widget

I have been trying to change the background color of the app widget on the fly for sometime now, with no success.

I had found one solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726295/android-changing-linearlayout-in-a-widget) which we have been using.

Problem is we already have 8 layout files for 8 background colors, which is really difficult to maintain.

We would also like to add a color picker so that users can select their own choice of color.

Is there a better way to work around the RemoteViews limitations?

Thanks...

Comment: I also want to know the answer. did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Won't

```
android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int color)
```

do the trick? The color is a 32 bits made up of four 8-bit values for alpha, red, green and blue. See `android.graphics.Color` for details, it also has helper functions for selecting colors. Or is that not supported by RemoteViews? I suppose it would correspond to

```
views.setInt(R.id.my_ll,"setBackgroundColor",myColor);
```

as stated in your link, don't know if that works though.

HTH.

Comment: Yes I believe it is not supported by RemoteViews. Accepted solution in the link was to create multiple layout files (One for each color).

Comment: As long as you are targeting 2.2 or higher, the setInt() method will allow you to do this.