# Android: change widget background

Tags: android, widget

is it possible to change widget bg without using imageview?

With image i change the bg like this:

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(EditPreferences.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ImageView01, R.drawable.blacktrans);          
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(EditPreferences.this, HelloWidget.class);
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(EditPreferences.this);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```

What if i am not using an imageview but setting the background of the relative layout?

```
     android:background="@drawable/blacktrans320x100"
```

Is it possible? I haven't found anything on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing CommonsWare from another topic:

> You cannot modify the background that way, due to limitations in the
>   RemoteViews API.
>
> What you can do is choose a different layout -- one with the
>   background you want -- when you create your RemoteViews instance for
>   this particular update.

[Android: Changing LinearLayout in a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726295/android-changing-linearlayout-in-a-widget)